# copiar archivos con php entre 2 servidores o también a mi local

Tags: php

Tengo windows y xampp. En principio necesito copiar los archivos de la carpeta `c:\prueba\1\` dentro de `c:\prueba\2\` , si existe el archivo primero renombrar y copiar a la carpeta `c:\prueba\2\back\` y luego si copiar a `c:\prueba\2\`.

Esto es para probar local. Necesito la misma funcionalidad para copiar un archivo `txt` de un servidor a otro (la ruta sería del estilo "http://177.12.12.20/file1/1/pepe.jpg" a "http://180.18.20.25/file1/1/pepe.jpg").

¿Alguna ayuda o ejemplo?. Esto es lo que intenté iniciar pero no me funciona:

```
<?php
    $file1="masitas.jpg";

    $ruta_origen='C:\prueba\1\';
    $ruta2='C:\prueba\2\';
    
    $copy = copy($ruta_origen . $file1, $local_file);

?>
```

No se como se define la ruta cuando quiero hacer pruebas de copia en local.

Comment: El caracter '\' es un caracter de escape, para poder escaparlo debes usar otro '\'. En otras palabras, las rutas deben ser: 'C:\\prueba\\1\\'. [TIP] Si no quieres complicarte, Windows tambien soporta el separador `/`. Por otro lado, no puedes copiar archivos por el protocolo http[s]. Necesitas acceder al sistema de archivos de ambos servidores, ya sea por ftp, ssh, etc. Puedes enviarle la instrucción vía http(s) o api, pero la ejecución de la misma es entre el sistema de archivos.

Comment: Gracias ! , respecto a lo q comentas de : Necesitas acceder al sistema de archivos de ambos servidores, ya sea por ftp, ssh, etc. Puedes enviarle la instrucción vía http(s) o api, pero la ejecución de la misma es entre el sistema de archivos. Si tengo un archivo en la ip 180.000.000.1 y quiero copiar a otro servidor en la ip 185.000.000.1 , tienes un ejemplo como podría ?